# How can I program an Arduino Pro Mini with an ESP8266-01 connected to its TX and RX?

Tags: esp8266, programming, arduino-ide, arduino-pro-mini

I am working on a project that uses an Arduino Pro Mini to gather information from various sensor. Once the readings are taken I turn on an ESP-01 from a separate dedicated 3.3v power supply. The ESP-01 then sends the info to Adafruit.

This works fine. My problem lies in programming the Arduino Pro Mini. If I program it separately (without the ESP attached) using FTDI connected to my Mac using Arduino IDE everything goes great and program is successful.

If however I have the whole thing connected up on the PCB board where the TX on the Pro Mini is connected to RX on ESP-01 and the RX on Pro Mini to TX on ESP I can't get the program to upload. It just keeps trying to connect but can't even though it recognizes the board via the USB port.

Is there anyway to work around this without unsoldering things. I just want to tweak a bit of the programming on the Arduino Pro Mini. Not a big deal but I would be nice. I soldered a female header onto the end of the Pro Mini for programming.

I am enclosing a visual of the connection set up when I am trying to program Arduino Pro Mini.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: (a) Can you get access to pins 11,12 ,13 and Reset on the PCB mounted Promini and (b) have you another Arduino (or ICSP programmer)  available?

Comment: Pretty sure you can use OTA uploads to the pro mini via the attached ESP01. A bit of googling should confirm.

Comment: Pins 11, 12, and 13 are connected to other things on PCB mounted Pro Mini.  I do have other FTDI programmers and have tried different ones in different USB ports with no difference.  I don't know if the small update to the Pro Mini is that important that I want to go through the hassles of setting up OTA but that is an interesting idea.  Thanks.  Since it works with another Pro Mini connected up the same wayI think it has to do with maybe the header on the Pro Mini.  I'm going to try to remove it and resolder another one on.  Or maybe just live with what is programmed already.

Comment: You could try connecting a temporary jumper between the esp01 pin CH_PD and GND. Find a pinout diagram. It is one of the pins broken out on the 8 pin header. This is the "enable" pin of the esp01. Grounding it will have the effect of disabling the esp01 and may prevent it interfering with the attempt to upload code to the pro-mini. This would be less hassle than attempting an ICSP type upload. If this works, I'll add a formal answer to the question.